# Using html style within <img> tag in opera mini

Tags: html, image, styles

I have a mobile website and i am using `style="max-width= 85%;"` in img tag to fit the image in browser screen. Everything working fine. But in opera mini it is not working and causing the page zoom out and trying to show a big image. Why ? And how can i fix that??

Comment: css uses `:`, not `=`. try `max-width: 85%` instead.

Comment: I am sorry but that i have done already. But still not working in opera mini. Working in other browsers. It seems a problem with opera mini. It is ignoring thae style

Answer (score 0):

The code you have given above must be `max-width: 85%;` to function properly. Use `:` instead of `=`

Try doing width:85%; to stretch image always

Comment: I am sorry but that i have done already. But still not working in opera mini. Working in other browsers. It seems a problem with opera mini. It is ignoring thae style

Comment: have you tried only width:85%; to stretch the image... I think it will work